# Serializar imagen en c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Mi problema es que al hacer click en el botón abrir quiero que, automáticamente, se abra, se pueda ver, y se serialice con la ruta *.poo en la misma ubicación donde abrí la imagen, todo esto solo con el botón abrir, ya que quiero eliminar el botón deserializar.

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo hacer eso?

```
private void btnAbrir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ventana = new OpenFileDialog();
            ventana.Filter = "Archivo JPG|*.jpg|Archivo PNG|*.png";

            if (ventana.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(ventana.FileName);
            }  
        }

        private void btnserializar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog ventana = new SaveFileDialog();
            ventana.Filter = "Archivo Binario|*.poo";

            if(ventana.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileStream fichero = new FileStream(ventana.FileName,FileMode.Create);

                BinaryFormatter formatoBinario = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatoBinario.Serialize(fichero, this.pictureBox1.Image);

                fichero.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Serializado Okey");
            }

        }

        private void btndeserializar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ventana = new OpenFileDialog();
            ventana.Filter = "Archivo Binario|*.poo";

            if (ventana.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileStream fichero = new FileStream(ventana.FileName, FileMode.Open);

                BinaryFormatter formatoBinario = new BinaryFormatter();


                this.pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)formatoBinario.Deserialize(fichero);

                fichero.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Deserializado Okey");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola Helen, bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. No me queda muy claro, lo que quieres es que en un solo botón se hagan ambas operaciones? Es decir, que se asigne al pictureBox y se serialize en un archivo con extensión .poo en la misma ruta? o ¿qué es exactamente lo que buscas?

Comment: Sí, eso exactamente. Pero quiero que se guarde la imagen serializada, en la misma ruta que se encontraba, con el nombre que tenía, más la extensión .poo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que lo primordial para hacer lo que quieres, es *cambiar* la extensión del nombre de archivo, para ello, puedes valerte de la función [`ChangeExtension`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.changeextension?view=netframework-4.7.2) de la clase `Path`, que la usarías de la siguiente manera:

```
string nuevoNombre = Path.ChangeExtension(ventana.FileName, ".poo");
```

Dónde `ventana` es la variable de tipo `OpenFileDialog` que ya tenías declarada.

Para que te orientes, un ejemplo parecido a lo que quieres hacer sería:

```
OpenFileDialog ventana = new OpenFileDialog();
ventana.Filter = "Archivo JPG|*.jpg|Archivo PNG|*.png";

if (ventana.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    //acá carga la imagen al pictureBox
    nuevoNombre = Path.ChangeExtension(ventana.FileName, ".poo");
    FileStream fichero = new FileStream(nuevoNombre, FileMode.Create); //acá usas el nombre nuevo
    //Y ya sigues con el proceso para serializar...
}
```

Espero que con el ejemplo te puedas orientar, ya te queda a ti juntar las piezas del rompecabezas para armar la solución final.